# user access control getting user level

Tags: php, sql, database

I have a login form with `<form method="POST" action="formdata.php">`
In **formdata.php** I have the variables as
`$n=$_POST['name'];
$p=$_POST['password'];`

Then after succesful login I direct to the page **"main.php"**.

From main.php I want to check user level and based on user level restrict the pages that a user can access.

To get user level I included

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT level FROM member WHERE  userName='$n'");
$level=mysql_fetch_array($query);
if ($level==3){
echo "level 3 user";
    }
```

But I don't think I get the user **level** from the database to the variable $level correctly as it doesn't executes `if ($level==3)`.

Can't I use `$n` in  `WHERE  userName='$n'` because $n is declared in formdata.php ?

How can I get the **level** field value from the database?

Answer (score 0):

Your usage is wrong. It must be

```
if($level[0] == 3)
```

or

```
if($level['level'] == 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look into [Sessions](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp)

When validating the login in formdata.php, save the user's data into session:

```
<?php
session_start();
// validate user credentials
$_SESSION['user_level'] = 3;
$_SESSION['user_name']  = 'John Smith';
```

You can then access this data in your main.php

```
<?php
session_start();
echo("Hello $_SESSION[user_name]!");

if ($_SESSION['user_level'] > 3) {
    echo "You have admin access";
} else {
    echo "You're a regular user";
}
```

Just remember to call `session_start()` on every page where you need to access session data. Also read up on the subject before using my sample, it's only a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_fetch_array` return array don't use it as a string

this condition would be

```
$level=mysql_fetch_array($query);
if ($level['level']==3){
     echo "level 3 user";
    }
```

Comment: I made the change as` $query=mysql_query('SELECT level FROM member WHERE userName="'.$n.'"');
$level=mysql_fetch_array($query);
if($level['level'] == 3) {
 echo "level 3 user";
 }` But still doesn't work

Comment: print_r($level) and paste the result of it

Comment: Nothing gets printed as the result

Comment: its means problem in your query it does't give any result

Comment: try to print your query and run in phpmyadmin sql

Comment: when I execute this query from formdata.php `$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM member WHERE `userName`='$n' AND `password`='$p'");` it successfully logs in the user. But I am using `$query=mysql_query('SELECT * FROM member WHERE userName="'.$n.'"');` from main.php and not from formdata.php. Can't I access the variable $n from main.php ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77881/discussion-between-saty-and-sam-rox).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here '$n'

check this : 
$query=mysql_query('SELECT level FROM member WHERE  userName="'.$n.'"');